Strange behaviour of the shortcut Super + Left and Right arrows with 24.04
In Ubuntu 22.04 I used Super+Left and Super+Right to resize a window to half of the display and to move it to the left or the right.
With Ubuntu 24.04 (both on a machine upgraded from 22.04 and on a machine with a fresh 24.04 installation) these keybindings do this as expected, but instead of terminating immediately afterwards, the display hangs and shows the list of open applications as if I were still pressing Super. I have to press Esc to go back working.
Is there a way to return to the previous behaviour?

The keyword here is "tiling". The popup shown by default is to select an open app that should fill the other half of the screen after tiling.
You can disable this behavior in Ubuntu under GNOME Settings, then Ubuntu Desktop -> Enhanced Tiling -> Tiling Popup

Alternatively, disable the setting on a terminal by running
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.tiling-assistant enable-tiling-popup false


Great! This is exactly what I was looking for. Now it works as I wanted. Thanks a lot!
